# How to pass a subprocess to a command with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, subshell, process-substitution

I'm trying to pass multiple outputs to a command using sub-processes. 
This is (a shortened version of) my command:

```
cat "$1"
one=cat "$1"
```

The output of `command <(echo "foo")` is

```
foo
/dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

Since `cat "$1"` works I assume the function has the permission to read the output of the sub-process', but permission is denied when I attempt to put it into a variable. Why is this, and is there any way around it?

Comment: I assume your `one=..` is meant to be something like `one=$(...)`

Comment: `one=cat "$1"` will try to run `$1` (`/dev/fd/63`) as an executable with the `one=cat` variable in its environment. That will fail with "Permission denied" because `/dev/fd/63` is a pipe, not a binary or script executable.

Comment: Because you tried to read from a pipe. `ls -la <(:)`  should show you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear.  But I'm guessing you have a command called `x` that does something like:

```
cat "$1"
one=$(cat "$1")
```

Now when you do `x <(echo "foo")` you get an error.

Now this is because of how the `<(...)` structure works.

Basically it runs `echo foo` and connects the output of that to a temporary file handle (`/dev/fd/63`) and then passes that as a parameter.

So now your first `cat` command reads the whole of the input.  Which means there's no input left.  So your *second* `cat` command has nothing to read.  And you get an error because the `echo` process has finished and there's no open handle to read.

In a simple form, you've done a special version of

```
echo "foo" | {
  cat
  one=$(cat)
}
```

but with clever file handling magic.

Comment: "And you get an error because the echo process has finished and there's no open handle to read." I can't follow that. I would expect the second cat to get an EOF without error. How does that explain the `/dev/fd/63: Permission denied`?

Comment: It's likely a combination of your shell, kernel and other stuff.  On my machine (CentOS 7) I don't get any error at all.  There could be timing issues at play as well.  It's possible some kernel will spot the closed write side and give an EPERM for an attempt to open the closed filehandle.  FWIW, with ksh93 it picks the lowest unopened handle (`/dev/fd4`) so we're definitely in the space of "lots of unknowns".  Although it's very possible the OP _also_ had bad command syntax and was trying to execute the path!

Comment: I'm not the OP; see my [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569175/how-to-pass-a-subprocess-to-a-command-with-bash#comment1058551_569175) for a better IMHO explanation of the OP's error.

Comment: It's likely the OP had more than one error in their code; trying to execute the fd path and also expecting to read the input twice :-)  It's why I originally asked if they meant `one=$(...)` and answered assuming good code syntax :-)